# W2UI multi select not returning the latest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

I am using [W2UI's multi select](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-enum) to choose items.
I have populated the list from my server and that contains around 800 items.

```
$('#enum').w2field('enum', { 
                    items: arrDish, 
                    openOnFocus: true,
                    //onNew: displayValue,
                    onAdd: displayValue,
                    //markSearch:true,
                    onRemove: function (event) {
                        alert("removed");

                    },

                    renderItem: function (item, index, remove) {
                        var html = remove + '<span class="fa-trophy" style="'+ pstyle +'; margin-left: -4px;"></span>' + item.text;
                        //displayValue();
                        return html;


                    },
                    renderDrop: function (item, options) {
                        return '<span class="fa-star" style="'+ pstyle +'"></span>' + item.text;

                    }


                });
                function displayValue() { 
                    console.log($('#enum').data('selected'));
                    selectedDish=getCol($('#enum').data('selected'),'text');
                    console.log(selectedDish); // am getting the values in the console log here but without the latest item
                }
                //below function is also working properly
                function getCol(matrix, col){
                    var column = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
                        column.push(matrix[i][col]);
                    }
                    return column;
                }
```

The problem is that, when I execute the `displayValue` function to get the latest list of selected items, the last item is missing.

I tried adding a simple alert box on `onAdd` and  `onRemove` option, What I can see is that, these alerts appear before the item is added in the list i.e when I close the alert, the item is added/removed from the list.

My requirement is that, I want to refresh my chart whenever the list of selected items is changed(along with the latest selected list).

**Sample case:**

When I select 1 item in the list, the console prints "0" items, again when I select 2 items, the console prints 1 item and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that all of the `event` functions of W2UI's multi select are "before" events, and not after (the w2ui's library triggers the events before the actual event, and not after).

I searched for `after` events, and couldn't find any, however - you can use the `event` object to get the information about the current item that is about to be added to your multi-select.

```
function displayValue(e) {
    console.log($('#enum').data('selected'));
    consloe.log(e.item);
}
```

> Note the `e` parameter in the function name `displayValue(e)`

Using your current code I just added the new item to the `selectedDish` array:

```
function displayValue(e) {
    // The item that we got in this event:
    console.log(e.item);

    // The data we selected before the selection of the new item
    console.log($('#enum').data('selected'));

    // Array of the current selected items
    selectedDish=getCol($('#enum').data('selected'),'text');

    // Add the text of the item we selected
    selectedDish.push(e.item.text)

    // Now the selectedDish contains all the values, including the last one that was selected
    console.log(selectedDish); 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But this approach sort of make this whole thing solve only half of the problem. I mean, If I want to perform a search after a item has been added or removed, I need to store the items in another array and perform the search on that as the `selected` doesn't return the latest list.